# Disk read and write in C & garbage values

Tags: c, file, char

I am experimenting with fread() and fwrite(), and I ran into some problems.

Mainly, my code looks like this:

```
//write back to file
char buffers[sizeof(char)*4];

FILE *fp = fopen("test", "wb");
char data[] = {'C', 'S', 'C'};
fwrite(data, sizeof(char), sizeof(data)/sizeof(char), fp);

fread(buffers, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffers)/sizeof(char), fp);

for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(buffers); i++) {
    printf("%c", buffers[i]);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to first write, a file named "test" that has CSC as its content, then reading the content back in command line. However, after finishing the for loop, the command line gives garbage values (????(v?Z????Z???Y???Y????V?Y???Y???Y????) , instead of CSC that should be printed. Why is this so?

Comment: You need to close the file and reopen for reading.

Comment: Aside: `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

Comment: If you want to read from the file, you need to specify "w+". Also, C11 draft standard n1570: *7.21.5.3 The fopen function 7 When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the
above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos, or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function,[...]*

Comment: @JohnnyMopp When I fclose(fp), and open it again with fp = fopen("test", "rb+"), it does give me the right answer at the end, but has other garbage values in front (i.e. ?x; ?-?Њ???p+???????????????$?؉????????؉???p+CSC).

Comment: check the return value of `fread()`

Comment: @Corp.andLtd. That's strange since the `for` loop should only print 4 chars since, as previously mentioned, `sizeof(char) = 1`.

Comment: There's zero reason to do `x y[sizeof(x)*n]`. That's only relevant with dynamic allocation like `malloc`, which you're not doing here. That should be `char buffer[4]`. Note "buffer" as there's only one.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I suspected that there are other codes that were interacting with this snippet, so I took it out and it seems to work fine! Except I need to compile this for every run... otherwise it gives "./test: line 1: CSC: command not found" error.